# how to track a deletion in the future?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in my Datamart; users are supposed to only read from that table… I checked and the count of the table went down, meaning, someone, a SP or a job, deleted records, and I sense it is not the first time.

My question: what is the less invasive, and simpler way of tracking this: I do not want to prevent this; I want to get the person’s name, or the SP/Job name, and the exact time it happened.

I am using: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64): Business Intelligence Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

I have ‘simple’ recovery model, I assume tracking it in the past is really challenging, so I am happy with retrieving this information in the future.

Comment: Either turn on CDC (depending on your SQL Server version) or add a trigger. If you've handed out SQL Server logins then there's probably no way to find out who it really is. If you're using windows authentication then you have a better chance

Comment: That's a job for [SQL Server Audit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx), available since 2008.  Another option is to enable change tracking, it's lighter than CDC and available in all SQL Server editions. It doesn't capture the same information though

Comment: I have seen that cdc will not provide you the exact login or sp/job that deleted one row on an specific table. The only way I can achieve this is with a trigger I guess. I am trying to find an example.

Comment: "users are supposed to only read from that table" - then why not revoke any permissions they have to do anything else to that table and wait to see who/what complains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a AFTER DELETE trigger on your table and log deleted values into a history log table with user information and deletion time, etc as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.myTableDeleteTrigger
    ON dbo.myTable
AFTER DELETE
AS

  INSERT INTO myTableHistory (
    -- columns from myTable
    DeletedDate,
    DeletedByUserId
  )
  SELECT
    -- delete column values from Deleted temp table
    GETDATE(),
    USER_ID()
  FROM Deleted

GO
```

I used a similar [trigger to log data changes](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-sql-server-trigger-example-to-log-changes-history.aspx) for insert, update and delete DMLs on a SQL database table as I explained in the referred tutorial

Comment: great answer! I used USER_ID(), and I got insertd '11' in the table... not sure if that is a person, or a job... how can I know exactly who '11' is?

Answer (score 0):

This below code will generate the Triggers for every table in your database.

Note: You can exclude the tables which you don't want the track in CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT TAB.name FROM SYS.objects TAB
where TAB.type='U'
)
SELECT '
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_'+NAME+'_LOG] ON [dbo].['+NAME+'] 
FOR UPDATE,DELETE
AS
INSERT INTO LOG_'+NAME+'
(LOG_DTE,'+(SELECT STUFF((
SELECT ', '+ COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=NAME FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))+')



    SELECT getdate(),'+(SELECT STUFF((
SELECT ', '+ COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=NAME FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))+'
    from deleted 

    PRINT ''AFTER TRIGGER FIRED''
' FROM CTE order by name OFFSET 81 ROWS FETCH NEXT 571 ROWS ONLY
```

But before you need to create a table for every table with the name prefix Log_ of actual table.

Ex: If you have table `Employee (Eid int, EName Varchar(250))`

You need to have a table like

`Log_Employee (LOG_EID int identity,Log_DTe Datetime, EID int FK, EName Varchar(250))`